# After committing, resetting head and then checking out the commit, git does not restore removed files

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-reset

After committing changes, I ran `git reset --hard HEAD^` mistakenly and it caused me to lose the files in that committed changes.

I am trying to recover these files.

When I do `git reflog` it shows that previous commit, `thatCommit`, so I then proceed with:

`git checkout thatCommit`

However, none of the files are restored.

When I then type `git checkout` it prints out all the files that have been deleted:

```
D path/to/deletedFile1
D path/to/deletedFile2
M path/to/changedFile1
M path/to/changedFile2
```

I'd like the deleted files and changed files to be restored, but I cannot see `path/to/deletedFile1` in my repo/branch.

How can I recover these files?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
git checkout thatCommit -- .
```

(to force the working tree to be reinitialize to that commit content)

Or:

```
git reset --hard thatCommit
```